# FB.logout in JS project gives error "Expression is of type undefined, not function"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, facebook-login

I'm trying to add *Login with FB* on my react website.

```
FB.init({
    appId      : app_id,
    cookie     : true,
    xfbml      : true,
    version    : 'v5.0'
});
```

Followed by

```
FB.getLoginStatus(({status}) => {
    if (status === 'connected') {
        FB.logout();
    }
    FB.login((response) => {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            const {authResponse: {accessToken}} = response;
            onSuccess(accessToken);
        } else {
            onError({error: 'popup_closed_by_user'});
        }
    }, {scope: 'email'});
})
```

But it's opening the popup the first time (when `getLoginStatus` is not `connected`) and then the 2nd time it shows an error on the console

```
Uncaught b { innerError: undefined, message: "Expression is of type undefined, not function" }
```

Upon further investigation, I found that the error happens when the line `FB.logout()` is called.

What might I be doing wrong?

**NOTE** The same code was working until yesterday.

Comment: Having the same issue.

Comment: What happens if you pass a callback into the logout?

Comment: started having this issue too

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems like `FB.logout` now has reqired param: `cb`.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.logout/

Not sure when it became mandatory, but it is not working without it anymore.

Comment: I swear to God the people over at Facebook seriously needs to reconsider throwing proper exception messages. How hard could it have been to return a `logout requires a mandatory callback function`. As opposed to the extremely convoluted `Expression is of type undefined, not function`. Or better, `if (typeof cb !== "function") return;`. -__-

Comment: @JayGhosh Even some Microsoft APIs do the same. No proper response